# add "counting" column to a data frame with certain conditions

Tags: r, loops, counting

I have a data frame with different account and win or lose record. I want to count how many times a person has lost in a row.

```
df <- data.frame(account_number =c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3),
                 win_lose = c(-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1))

> df
       account_number win_lose
1               1       -1
2               1       -1
3               1       -1
4               1        1
5               1       -1
6               1       -1
7               1       -1
8               2       -1
9               2       -1
10              2        1
11              2        1
12              2        1
13              3        1
14              3       -1
```

Each account represents a person. The end results should look like this

```
           account_number win_lose   losing_streak
   1               1       -1             1
   2               1       -1             2
   3               1       -1             3
   4               1        1             0
   5               1       -1             1
   6               1       -1             2
   7               1       -1             3
   8               2       -1             1
   9               2       -1             2
   10              2        1             0
   11              2        1             0
   12              2        1             0
   13              3        1             0
   14              3       -1             1
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is `rleid` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'account_number`and`rleid`of 'win_lose`', we get the sequence of rows (`seq_len(.N)`) multiplied by 'win_lose < 0' so that all the FALSE values gets coerced to 0 and would be 0 by multiplying and the `TRUE` will be coerced to 1 and we get the sequence value by multiplying with 1.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, losing_streak := seq_len(.N) * (win_lose <0) ,
                        by = .(account_number, rleid(win_lose))]
df
#    account_number win_lose losing_streak
# 1:              1       -1             1
# 2:              1       -1             2
# 3:              1       -1             3
# 4:              1        1             0
# 5:              1       -1             1
# 6:              1       -1             2
# 7:              1       -1             3
# 8:              2       -1             1
# 9:              2       -1             2
#10:              2        1             0
#11:              2        1             0
#12:              2        1             0
#13:              3        1             0
#14:              3       -1             1
```

---

A `base R` option would be using `ave` (for group by) and with `rle`

```
with(df, ave(win_lose, account_number, FUN = 
  function(x) with(rle(x== -1), sequence(lengths) * rep(values, lengths))))
#[1] 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 1 2 0 0 0 0 1
```